# SweetCaptcha spam prevention possible

Tags: javascript, rest, captcha

I'm coding a form which requires SweetCaptcha verification. When developing REST API for the form I've realized that I can use always the same pair sckey / scvalue.

In my thinking this means that any spammer could solve the puzzle once and then send me tons of spam requests.

Am I right?

Thanks on advance.

Comment: Yes you're right. That does not sound like a very good solution you've found there. I'd suggest going for something else - like reCaptcha https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

Comment: I wouldn't use it at all anymore: https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/06/sweetcaptcha-service-used-to-distribute-adware.html